# How to restrict the XSD of SAML 2.0 Authentication Context

Tags: xml, xsd, saml-2.0, xsd-validation

I have been trying to find a solution to my problem is the last 10 days, and I found nothing.
So, I am trying to restrict the Authentication Context XML Schema Definition of SAML 2.0. The XSD document is accessible at http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-authn-context-types-2.0.xsd.

The part that I am trying to restrict is the one related to this part of the XSD document:

```
<xs:complexType name="PasswordType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="Length" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="Alphabet" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="Generation" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="Extension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="ExternalVerification" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="RestrictedPassword" type="RestrictedPasswordType"/>
<xs:complexType name="RestrictedPasswordType">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:restriction base="PasswordType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Length" type="RestrictedLengthType" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="Generation" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="Extension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="ExternalVerification" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Well, I do not know how to restrict the RestrictedPassword complex Type. Below is my XSD, that tries to restrict the original XSD document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema version="2.0"
       targetNamespace="urn:m:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:K"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns="urn:m:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:K"           
       finalDefault="extension"
       blockDefault="substitution">

<xs:redefine schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-authn-context-types-2.0.xsd">    

    <xs:complexType name="RestrictedPasswordType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="RestrictedPasswordType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="Length" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element ref="Generation"/>
                    <xs:element ref="Extension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="ExternalVerification" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:redefine>    
</xs:schema>
```

When I try to validate this XSD in this tool http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.UwJAzK69h31 it returns me an error, that I do not know how to fix. This is the error:

```
Not valid. Error - Line 12, 51: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 51; rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles. Error - Line 12, 51: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 51; derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type 'RestrictedPasswordType'. The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base.
```

Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Domenech, Marlon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the instances of the new restricted type must also be valid for the base type. But in your schema, it is possible to define a `RestrictedPasswordType` which does not have a `Length` attribute (`minOccurs="0"`), which would be illegal for the base type `minOccurs="1"`. Making an element optional is not a restriction of the base type.

Removing `minOccurs='0'` from `Generation` is OK because having at least one element *is* a restriction.

Additionally your restriction references the `Length` element, which is not the same as the `Length` element defined in the base type. The `Length` element is of `LengthType` according to the base schema, and the `Length` element in the base type is a `RestrictedLengthType` which is a restriction of `LengthType`.

I believe that if you change the `<xs:element>` declaration in your derived type to:

```
<xs:element name="Length" type="RestrictedLengthType" minOccurs="1"/>
```

it should work, unless there are other problems.

**EDIT**: the other problems:

Since a new element `Length` is being declared in the `<complexType>` block, it needs to be declared as `"qualified"` otherwise it will not be part of the `targetNamespace` and the restriction will fail. To fix this you can either:

- Add a `form="qualified"` attribute to `<xs:element name="Length" ... />`, or
- Add an `elementFormDefault="qualified" attribute to the`` element.

More information here:

- About constraints for redefinitions: [XML Schema Part 1 - 4.2 Layer 2: Schema Documents, Namespaces and Composition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#layer2)
- About qualified elements and target namespaces: [XML Schema Primer - 3 Advanced Concepts I: Namespaces, Schemas & Qualification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#NS)

Comment: Hi, I agree with you. I changed the XSD, as suggested, and I have an error, as follows (it is the same error as before): Not valid. Error - Line 12, 51: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 51; rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles. Error - Line 12, 51: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 51; derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type 'RestrictedPasswordType'. The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base

Comment: The base document that you linked above does not declare a `targetNamespace`. But you declare one in the derived schema. The redefined schema should have the same `targetNamespace` as the base schema. Try removing the attributes `xmlns` and `targetNamespace` from your schema.

Comment: It worked. I took off the `xmlns` and `targetNamespace` and it worked. However, there are other similar documents that define a `xmlns` and a `targetNamespace` diferent of the original, and those are valid. Here is an example: [http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-authn-context-nomad-telephony-2.0.xsd . Do you know why?

Comment: You can keep your namespace declarations, but you need to use `elementFormDefault="qualified"` so the `Length` element is considered part of the target namespace (if for some reason you don't want to use that default for all element declarations, you can instead add the `form="qualified"` attribute in `<xs:element name="Length">`). The other elements are references so they won't have that problem.

Comment: In both cases it worked, either adding `form="qualified"` to the element as adding `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the `<schema>` element. But, let me try to understand. If I add `form="qualified"` to the element, that means that this element belongs to the original XSD namespace?

Comment: If the schema's root element does not include the attribute `elementFormDefault="qualified"`, all nested elements (e.g. inside a `complexType` block) that don't have the `form="qualified"` attribute will have no namespace (will belong to the null namespace). This does not apply to types. It also doesn't affect elements declared at the top level. More about this here: [XML Schema Primer - 3 Advanced Concepts I: Namespaces, Schemas & Qualification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#NS)

Comment: I read the document that you have indicated and understood the effect of changing the `form` attribute of the element. Thank you so much. :)